# What is the proper, safe way of cleaning C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages?

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I search online and this is supposed to be caching system. But if there are stuff there that I don't use often I would rather clear that up. But don't feel safe until knowing how visual studio uses it behind the scenes.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnC2x.png)

Comment: That appears to be the Visual Studio Installer download cache. I'm not sure you should delete anything there. Could cause problems during an update.

Comment: See Microsoft's [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/disable-or-move-the-package-cache?view=vs-2019) and [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/setup/cleaning-up-the-visual-studio-2017-package-cache/).

Answer (score 0):

You can disable package caching at install time.  You can also relocate the package cache folder to another drive, which requires changing a few Registry entries, copying the folder over and then deleting the original folder.  Permissions may need to be set on the new folder.

For details see [Moving or disabling the package cache for Visual Studio 2017](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/setup/moving-or-disabling-the-package-cache-for-visual-studio-2017/)